# Sailsjs permission denied creating folder when uploading a file

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-skipper

I have tried to run function to upload the file to the assets folder in the server. It work on my mac, but when I run it on CentOS 7 server, the error of mkdir permission denied occured.

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
  dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images')
},function (err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);

  return res.json({
    message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!'
  });
});
```

I have already set the permission folder, as you can see:

```
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root root   4096 May  6 12:49 assets
```

and to try execute it from folder app, already tried changing the `dirname` line into

```
dirname: sails.config.appPath + 'assets/images'
```

but still, the same error of EACCESS permission denied mkdir to the folder `/images` persist . Is there any workaround to let sailsjs apps generate a sub folder inside `/assets` folder without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems the OS does not allow sailsjs function `req.file().upload` to make a directory. So, the possible workaround is by using File System (`fs`) module to access low level operation for handling the `mkdir` task, then after the directory created, call the `req.file().upload`.